# Matching strings within two lists

Tags: python, string, list, function

Here is the problem:
I want to define function which will compare string ratios using fuzzy.ration() within 2 lists (not same size).
It should return entities from list 1, which have at least one ratio bigger than 60 compared with second.

```
def Matching(list1, list2):
    no_matching = []
    matching = []
    for item1 in list1:    
        for item2 in list2:        
            m_score = fuzz.ratio(item1, item2)
        if m.score < 60:
            no_matching.append(item1)
        if m.score > 60:
            matching.append(item1)
    return(matching, no_matching)
```

The output is not what I aim for. **Which part am I doing wrong** - in order to get only the items from list 1 if they have **at least one matching** from list 2 **bigger than 60**.

For example:

```
list1 = ["Real Madrid", "Benfica", "Lazio", "FC Milan"]
list2 = ["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Milan"]

for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        m_score = fuzz.ratio(item1, item2)
        print(item1, "&", item1, m_score)
```

Output is:

```
Real Madrid & Madrid 71 # greater than 60
Real Madrid & Barcelona 20
Real Madrid & Milan 12
Benfica & Madrid 15
Benfica & Barcelona 50
Benfica & Milan 17
Lazio & Madrid 36
Lazio & Barcelona 29
Lazio & Milan 20
FC Milan & Madrid 29
FC Milan & Barcelona 24
FC Milan & Milan 77 # greater than 60
```

The function output should be:

```
matching = ["Real Madrid", "FC Milan"] # since they have at least one ratio bigger than 60
no_matching = ["Benfica", "Lazio"]
```

Comment: What is your current output? Are you getting only the last matched element in list1?

Comment: You can check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are duplicate combinations in list1 and list2 that created copies in the `no_matching` list. Check if the element is already in the matching list. If yes, don't add to the `no_matching` list. The below code gives the expected output.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def Matching(list1, list2):
    no_matching = []
    matching = []
    m_score = 0
    for item1 in list1:    
        for item2 in list2:        
            m_score = fuzz.ratio(item1, item2)
            if m_score > 60:
                matching.append(item1)
        if m_score < 60 and not(item1 in matching):
            no_matching.append(item1)
    return(matching, no_matching)


list1 = ["Real Madrid", "Benfica", "Lazio", "FC Milan"]
list2 = ["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Milan"]
print(Matching(list1, list2))
```

Output:

```
(['Real Madrid', 'FC Milan'], ['Benfica', 'Lazio'])
```

Comment: Works good! Do you maybe have an advice for doing same computation with larger list?

Comment: @feration48 How big are the lists? The current solution does look suboptimal.

Comment: For instace list1 of 10.000 and list2 1200 entities. Following function will iterate 12 mil times :-/

Comment: Yes, if we can cut down the number of combinations generated we'll get a better solution.

Comment: Meaning that brute force approach should be replaced.... Did you had experience with similar problems? Is recordlinkage package better in this case?

Comment: @feration48 On the other hand, the requirement here is to find at least one match. So, I don't think we can cut down on the number of combinations. I have not worked on any similar problems. Maybe we can wait for another answer from the community.

Comment: @feration48 Just thought of something. Maybe, both the lists can be sorted then the inner loop can exit whenever there is a >60 `m_score`. This way iterations can be skipped.

Comment: @feration48 Can you upvote my answer if it was helpful? I think I have answered you original question about the loops.

Answer (score 7):

Especially given your comment about doing this on large lists (10.000 * 1.200), I would recommend the usage of [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) (I am the author). A solution using `RapidFuzz` could be achieved in the following way:

```py
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz
import numpy as np

list1 = ["Real Madrid", "Benfica", "Lazio", "FC Milan"]
list2 = ["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Milan"]

scores = process.cdist(
    list1, list2, scorer=fuzz.ratio,
    dtype=np.uint8, score_cutoff=60)
# scores is array([[71,  0,  0],
#                  [ 0,  0,  0],
#                  [ 0,  0,  0],
#                  [ 0,  0, 77]], dtype=uint8)

matches = np.any(scores, 1)
# matches is array([ True, False, False,  True])
```

This still processes the whole N*M matrix, but it is significantly faster than doing the same using `fuzzywuzzy`/`thefuzz`. When working with really large lists it is possible to enable multithreading in `process.cdist` by passing the named argument `workers` (e.g. `workers=-1` to use all available cores). The results above could be converted to the lists you showed in the example if that is needed:

```py
matching = [x for x, is_match in zip(list1, matches) if is_match]
# ['Real Madrid', 'FC Milan']
not_matching = [x for x, is_match in zip(list1, matches) if not is_match]
# ['Benfica', 'Lazio']
```

I benchmarked this solution on an [i7-8550U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i78550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html) using two large lists (10.000 * 1.200):

```
print(timeit(
"""
scores = process.cdist(
    list1, list2, scorer=fuzz.ratio,
    dtype=np.uint8, score_cutoff=60)

matches = np.any(scores, 1)

matching = [x for x, is_match in zip(list1, matches) if is_match]
not_matching = [x for x, is_match in zip(list1, matches) if not is_match]
""",
setup="""
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz
import numpy as np

list1 = ["Real Madrid", "Benfica", "Lazio", "FC Milan"] * 2500
list2 = ["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Milan"] * 400
""", number=1
))
```

which took 0.33 seconds. Using `workers=-1` reduced the runtime to 0.08 seconds.

Comment: This is a good find for me

Comment: Very well. Great work!

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
instead of run 2 for loops, you can run over all he combinations:

```
import itertools
new_list = list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
```

output:

```
[('Real Madrid', 'Madrid'), ('Real Madrid', 'Barcelona'), ('Real Madrid', 'Milan'), ('Benfica', 'Madrid'), ('Benfica', 'Barcelona'), ('Benfica', 'Milan'), ('Lazio', 'Madrid'), ('Lazio', 'Barcelona'), ('Lazio', 'Milan'), ('FC Milan', 'Madrid'), ('FC Milan', 'Barcelona'), ('FC Milan', 'Milan')]
```

you have a problem with indentation:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def Matching(list1, list2):
    no_matching = []
    matching = []
    m_score = 0
    for item1 in list1:    
        for item2 in list2:        
            m_score = fuzz.ratio(item1, item2)
            if m_score > 60:
                matching.append(item1)
        if m_score < 60 and not(item1 in matching):
            no_matching.append(item1)
    return(matching, no_matching)
```

Comment: Yes yes, but you skipped the part where I'm measuring distance between strings and getting the ratio (fuzzy.ration return numerical value). The problem seems to be storing the particular entities into list.

Comment: Take a look at the following edit

Comment: look now @feration48

Comment: This gives copies in the `no_matching` list.

Comment: @TalFolkman matching list is well. How to avoid repeating copies in no_match list?

Comment: try now @feration48

Comment: @TalFolkman That's it! Thanks! Any advice to do same computations with larger lists?

Comment: check the edit @feration48